# unable to apply condition on output of custom layer using keras layers module

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, gradient-descent

I want to apply a condition on the output of a dense layer. For this, I tried to customize the Dense layer of Keras but when I run my code I get the error 
`ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'scope0/rnn/while/lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(3, 512) dtype=float32>", "<tf.Variable 'scope0/rnn/while/lstm_cell/recurrent_kernel:0' shape=(128, 512) dtype=float32>", "<tf.Variable 'scope0/rnn/while/lstm_cell/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>", "<tf.Variable 'scope0/my_dense/kernel:0' shape=(128, 1) dtype=float32>", "<tf.Variable 'scope0/my_dense/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>"] and loss Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).`

I am putting the condition inside the call function where the output checked against a condition i.e. if<= 0.001 then the output should be one otherwise 0.0. The Dense layer I am using is just a copy of Keras Dense layer with some modifications in the `call` method which implement the above condition.

```py
class MyDense(Layer):

  def __init__(self,
               units,
               activation=None,
               use_bias=True,
               kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
               bias_initializer='zeros',
               kernel_regularizer=None,
               bias_regularizer=None,
               activity_regularizer=None,
               kernel_constraint=None,
               bias_constraint=None,
               apply_cond = False,

               **kwargs):
    if 'input_shape' not in kwargs and 'input_dim' in kwargs:
      kwargs['input_shape'] = (kwargs.pop('input_dim'),)

    super(MyDense, self).__init__(
        activity_regularizer=regularizers.get(activity_regularizer), **kwargs)
    self.units = int(units)
    self.activation = activations.get(activation)
    self.use_bias = use_bias
    self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
    self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)
    self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
    self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)
    self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
    self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)
    self.apply_cond = apply_cond


    self.supports_masking = True
    self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape)
    if tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1]) is None:
      raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
                       'should be defined. Found `None`.')
    last_dim = tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1])
    self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2,
                                axes={-1: last_dim})
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(
        'kernel',
        shape=[last_dim, self.units],
        initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
        regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
        constraint=self.kernel_constraint,
        dtype=self.dtype,
        trainable=True)
    if self.use_bias:
      self.bias = self.add_weight(
          'bias',
          shape=[self.units,],
          initializer=self.bias_initializer,
          regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
          constraint=self.bias_constraint,
          dtype=self.dtype,
          trainable=True)
    else:
      self.bias = None
    self.built = True

  def call(self, inputs):
    # print('in start of call apply_cond is: ', self.apply_cond)
    inputs = ops.convert_to_tensor(inputs)
    rank = common_shapes.rank(inputs)
    if rank > 2:
      # Broadcasting is required for the inputs.
      outputs = standard_ops.tensordot(inputs, self.kernel, [[rank - 1], [0]])
      # Reshape the output back to the original ndim of the input.
      if not context.executing_eagerly():
        shape = inputs.get_shape().as_list()
        output_shape = shape[:-1] + [self.units]
        outputs.set_shape(output_shape)
    else:
      outputs = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(inputs, self.kernel)
    if self.use_bias:
      outputs = nn.bias_add(outputs, self.bias)


    if self.activation is not None:
      outputs = self.activation(outputs)  # pylint: disable=not-callable

    if self.apply_cond:
      cond = tf.less_equal(outputs, tf.constant(0.00001), name='mycondition')
      return tf.where(cond,  tf.ones_like(outputs), tf.zeros_like(outputs), name='mywhere')

    return outputs

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape)
    input_shape = input_shape.with_rank_at_least(2)
    if tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1]) is None:
      raise ValueError(
          'The innermost dimension of input_shape must be defined, but saw: %s'
          % input_shape)
    return input_shape[:-1].concatenate(self.units)
```

How can I make the above code work?